# Assembly in model LARGE and I need to send to malloc #c

Tags: c, assembly

I need to link the allocated array from malloc to the pointers array: result array. How do I link the segment and the address; I know it is in DX:AX but how to link it?
Here is part of the code:

```
MOV GS,[BP+14]          ;segment of result array.
MOV BX,[BP+12]          ;adrs of result array.
CALL _malloc
ADD SP,2
MOV BX,temp
MOV WORD PTR[BX],AX     ;how to put DX segment??
```

Comment: Memory models in 2013? Really?

Comment: yeh...its part of a course

Comment: I hope it's the "history of computing" course. This stuff has been historic for almost 20 years.

Comment: In the age of memory models there was not yet a GS register. Only {CS,DS,SS,ES}

Answer (score 1):

That's not enough information, we don't know what exactly you are trying to do so I am gonna guess a little.

I assume `GS:BX` is a far pointer to the address where you want to store the return value from `malloc`. I further assume that this address is a far pointer itself. As such, something like this should work:

```
MOV WORD PTR GS:[BX], AX
MOV WORD PTR GS:[BX+2], DX
```

Adjust for your assembler's syntax if necessary.
I don't know what your `temp` is and why you wanted to use it there.